How to add decorations (window borders, drop-shadows) to certain apps under Wayland
With an upgrade (LTS > LTS) to (plain Ubuntu) 24.04, I find myself on Wayland. Certain apps, however, no longer have window borders or drop-shadows ("window decorations"?).
Examples of such apps are GIMP, Textadept (my long-time editor of choice), and Double Commander. There are quite a few others, too. (Others are just fine, of course: terminal, evince, libreoffice, etc., etc.)
In much web-searching, I see that I'm not alone in experiencing this, but most of the "help" I've found is aimed at app devs, not at numpty users.
Is there a non-intrusive, generalized way of getting the "naked" apps to look correct on a Wayland session? I could revert to XOrg, I suppose, but somehow that seems retrograde.
I suspect this might be a duplicate, but if it is, I haven't found something corresponding to it! Grateful for pointers, of course.
Update - with much more websearching, it's looking pretty much like this is a QT related issue, so I'm adding that tag. And it looks very much like it could be related to this bug report, although not 100% sure about that. (Maybe 97.3% sure...)
